# ES6 classes : what about instrospection?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, introspection

In ES5, I could check the existence of a "class" (constructor function) on the window object:

```
if (window.MyClass) {
... // do something
}
```

In ES6, [according to this article](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html), globally-declared classes are globals, but not properties of the global object (`window`, on browsers):

> But there are now also global variables that are not properties of the global object. In global scope, the following declarations create such variables:
>
> - `let` declarations
> - `const` declarations
> - Class declarations

So if I can't use `if (window.MyClass)`, is there a way to do the same?

Actually is there a proper way to do this without using window object ?

Comment: "meaning that they are not accessible on the window global scope"... What does hoisting have to do with global scope?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 
Indeed, sorry for the confusion, nothing to see with hoisting. Anyway, would you have any recommendation to check for class existence ? es6 modules maybe ?

Comment: Check if the root module declaring the class is declared ?

Comment: Hi, i was thinking to organize my work in modules. If i export some classes in a module. I could check on that module if the class exist right ? (just an ieda)

Comment: Great question. Just ran into this problem today when trying to refactor a project using pseudoclasses into the new ES6 classes. Broke my window[className] invocations (needed this because I was pulling the class names from input buttons w/ jquery).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> In ES5, we could wheck the existence of a class on the window object

Only if the constructor function was a global, which is poor practice.

> In ES6, [according to this article](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html), globally-declared classes are globals, but not properties of the global object...

Correct. (The same is true of `let` and `const` declarations at global scope.) This is defined in [§8.1.1.4: Global Environment Records](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-global-environment-records):

> A global Environment Record is logically a single record but it is specified as a composite encapsulating an object Environment Record and a declarative Environment Record. The object Environment Record has as its base object the global object of the associated Realm. This global object is the value returned by the global Environment Record’s GetThisBinding concrete method. *(E.g., the global object referenced by `window` on browsers — T.J.)* **The object Environment Record component of a global Environment Record contains the bindings for all built-in globals (clause 18) and all bindings introduced by a *FunctionDeclaration*, *GeneratorDeclaration*, or *VariableStatement* contained in global code. The bindings for all other ECMAScript declarations in global code are contained in the declarative Environment Record component of the global Environment Record.**

*(My emphasis)* So the things that used to go on the global object in ES5 and earlier still do (plus generators, because it would have been even more confusing if they didn't), but the *new* things (`let`, `const`, and `class` declarations) **don't**. They're globals, but not properties of the global object.

Back to your question...

> So if I can't use `if (window.MyClass)`, is there a way to do the same?

You could use

```
if (typeof MyClass === "function") {
```

...since `typeof` on an unresolvable symbol doesn't throw a `ReferenceError`. This also has the advantage of checking whether `MyClass` is in scope for the code, even if it's *not* global.

There's a gotcha there though: If that code is in the same scope where `MyClass` is declared via `class` (or `let` or `const`) but it's *above* `MyClass` in that scope, even the `typeof` check will throw a `ReferenceError`, because you can't access the binding it creates **at all** (not even with `typeof`) before the `class` (or `let` or `const`).

E.g., this will throw:

```
if (typeof MyClass === "function") {  // ReferenceError here
    // Yup, it's defined
    // ...
}
// ...
class MyClass {
}
```

The space from the beginning of the scope to the `class`, `let`, or `const` line is called the *temporal dead zone* (TDZ) and you can't access the variable binding at all. Consequently, you have to catch the `ReferenceError`:

```
let exists = false;
try {
    exists = typeof MyClass === "function";
} catch (e) {
}
```

> Actually is there a proper way to do this without using window object ?

Until JavaScript modules make it to broad browser support, there are a couple of ways:

1. Use an Asynchronous Module Definition library of some kind to handle loading your modules. Some examples: RequireJS, SystemJS, CommonJS
2. Have a single global variable that you'll use to refer to an object, and make your various application globals properties of that object. Here's a typical way to do that:

   ```
   var MyApp = MyApp || {};
   if (!MyApp.ThisModule) {                  // You can leave this `if` out
                                             // if there's no chance of the file
                                             // being loaded more than once
       MyApp.ThisModule = function(module) {
           module.MyClass = class MyClass {
               // ...class definition here...
           }
       }({});
   }
   ```

This also gives you a handy scope (the anonymous function) in which to put any module-level globals.