# ES6 class store

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I just can't find out where the references to declared ES6 classes are stored, I would have expected them in the window Object, bit they don't appear there.

I don't think it's a duplicate of [ES6 classes : what about instrospection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321636/es6-classes-what-about-instrospection) since he is asking for a existance check of a class, what I want is a list of available classes.

For example:

```
class Test {
    constructor() {

    }
}

window.Test // undefined
```

What I want is a list of all classes that extend a class of mine

To clarify that I have a structure that looks something like this:

```
class Base {
    constructor(components) {
        for(let component of components) {
            window[component](); // window.Test2 not defined
        }
    }

    start() {
        new this();
    }
}

class Test2 extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

class Test extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super(['Test2','Test2']);
    }
}

Test.start();
```

That's just an abstraction of my structure, in short I have to use strings at `super(['Test2', 'Test2'])`

At the moment I'm doing something like this

```
Base.register(Test2);
```

for every class and I want to get rid of that.

Comment: You can't just "get a list" of all classes. You're gonna have to do something terrible, like create a global object to store all of them in.

Comment: You could try starting with a known class, like String, and ascending the prototype chain until you find other classes.  They may not all be in the same place, or all inherit from the same things.

Comment: *"What I exactly want is a list of all classes that extend a class of mine"* That's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Class expressions` to store them in some sort of array, although I probably wouldn't do it, if I were you.

```
var Test = class Test {
   constructor() {

   }
}

allClasses.push(Test);
```

Comment: It's not exactly worth an answer if it's something you wouldn't do.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript classes are introduced in ECMAScript 6 and are syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax is not introducing a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript. JavaScript classes provide a much simpler and clearer syntax to create objects and deal with inheritance.

Basically ES6 classes are compiled to plain old-fashioned Javascript functions. You may "store" them at the window object but this is a major pitfall as you are killing the whole module patter ES6 introduced.

Answer (score 0):

If you want sort of a "module" of classes, you could theoretically do something like this:

```
// some-class.js

export default class SomeClass {}
```

Then:

```
// another-class.js

export default class AnotherClass {}
```

And your entry file:

```
// index.js

import SomeClass from './some-class.js' // extensions optional; here just for clarity
import AnotherClass from './another-class.js'

export default {
  SomeClass,
  AnotherClass
}
```

If you have all of those embedded in the same directory (we'll call the directory `example`), you can just import that entire module wherever you need it:

```
// something-that-requires-your-module.js

// this will by default enter through the `index.js` file of your `example` directory
import Example from './example';

console.log(Example.SomeClass);
console.log(Example.AnotherClass);
```