# How to access a bundled ES6 class in inline <script>

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm using Webpack to transpile my ES6 classes. Let's say there's a `Service` class inside the bundle that can be imported by other bundled scripts.

```
class Service {
    constructor() {
        //
    }

    someMethod(data) {
        //
    }
}

export default Service;
```

Now I've got a tiny inline script in the HTML body *(pseudo-code below)* that needs to call a method in that `Service` class with data that is inserted server-side using a template engine such as Twig or Blade. Of course creating a new `Service` object won't work...

```
<body>
    ...
    <script>
        var data = {{ $json_server_data }}; 

        var service = new Service;

        Service.someMethod(data);
    </script>
</body>
```

I'd really like the server data to be available inline as it prevents an additional asynchronous call. And polluting the window namespace with the `Service` class feels like throwing away the benefits of a class loader...

How would you tackle this?  Suggestions about taking a different approach are also welcome of course.

Comment: Show us your webpack setting. You should be able to choose there which exports from which modules you want to have available how. And now, there is nothing wrong with using the global scope for this, that's what it was made for. When you need the `Service`, it's not an unnecessary pollution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Service class won't be available outside the scope of the bundled javascript. So you probably want to make it [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711603/javascript-es6-class-definition-not-accessible-in-window-global), and you can do that by attaching it into the window object.

```js
// Service.js
class Service {
    constructor() {
        //
    }

    someMethod(data) {
        //
    }
}

window.Service = Service;

export default Service;


// usage
let myService = new Service();
```

Comment: I've updated my OP to include the Service class code. Note that I'm exporting the class in contrast to your snippet. When requesting the Service object inline I'm getting a object not defined error.

Comment: Isn't there any other possibilty? Attaching it to the window feels like throwing away the gains of a class loader...

Comment: The other way is to get the json_server_data from within your app, which is probably cleaner. If you want your Service class to be visible in the inline script, it has to be global.