# How do I avoid adding JavaScript ES6 module exports to global scope for use in normal script blocks?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I've so far managed to avoid hardcore JavaScript programming but it looks like that is coming to an end. In gearing up for a major new project, I'm trying to get my head around best practices in 2018. I've been reading a lot about different module approaches and have made use of some like Dojo's AMD-based modules. In thinking about how to design my own module architecture, it seems like ES6 is the right way to go for new development.  So far I understand the import/export syntax and have gotten some simple modules to work. But my current technique for loading the modules back in HTML and using them just "feels wrong". Let me boil down what I have working so far.

Module foo.js

```
import (bar} from '/Scripts/bar.js'

export function foo() {
    bar();
    console.log("I'm in foo");
}
```

Module bar.js

```
export function bar() {
    console.log("I'm in bar");
}
```

index.html

```
<head>
    <script type="module">
        import {foo} from "/Scripts/foo.js"
        window.foo = foo;   // save for later but "feels wrong"
   </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        // foo();      // doesn't work - foo by itself is only defined in the module scope
        window.foo();  // unless "stashed" somewhere else
    </script>
</body>
```

Maybe this is proper technique (and I found [an older question that did basically the same as me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516242/how-to-access-a-bundled-es6-class-in-inline-script)), but it still doesn't feel like I should be polluting the global namespace like this. Assuming that's bad, what else should I be doing?

Comment: If you want the function available globally, the only way to achieve that is to put it on the global scope. Unless I'm misunderstanding your question? A little bit nicer way to put things on the global scope is to have some sort of `globals` object that contains all of your globals, rather than putting the actual function/property names on `window` which can potentially cause conflicts. So you would say `globals.foo()` instead of `window.foo()`

Comment: Put it in something *in*  the global namespace, just like before ES6?

Comment: @mhodges: Yes, that's essentially the question. You're right there are other containers that could be used besides `window` like a simple properties store as you say or a "namespace" or whatever. It felt like the module import should be introducing a scope of it's own at this level and I was just missing the proper syntax (and I did my due diligence/searching before asking). But sounds like that's just not the way it works. I guess I should accept @mhodges comment as the answer.

Comment: @JimHanks If you use a bundler/module loader like Webpack, you can absolutely do what you are trying to do. Each js file would contain its list of imports that only get loaded whenever that file is loaded. Your global scope does not get polluted, and everything is self-contained. If that is what you are trying to achieve, I would highly suggest that method. If you are not wanting to use a bundler/module loader, however, I think using your own namespace with a globals object will be your best bet

Comment: @JimHanks I would also add that (in 2018), for medium-to-large-sized projects, using a bundler/module loader is absolutely the way to go. Webpack is by far the easiest and most capable one out there currently. There are great guides out there on how to get up and running.

Comment: @mhodges: agree. I'm not using a bundler yet but I'm sure I will and maybe that's "closer to the truth" about what I'm still missing. But If you can submit your first comment as an answer, I'll accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the function available globally, the only way to achieve that is to put it on the global scope (AKA the `window` object).

A little bit nicer way to put things on the global scope, however, is to have some sort of `globals` object that contains all of your globals, rather than putting the function/property names directly on the `window` object which can potentially cause conflicts with other third-party libraries.

So you would say `globals.foo()` instead of `window.foo()`

Answer (score 0):

A *function* can be accessed everywhere by re-importing it to many modules.

You only need to add objects to global scope where *state* is maintained and required across modules.