# How to make the export functions global after an import() call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, import, module, global

So we have this function in JavaScript:

```
// main.js
import('./module.js');
```

Then we have the module file:

```
// module.js
export function SomeFunctionA() {
}
  
export function SomeFunctionB() {
}
```

Is it possible to use the import() call and make all "export " functions from the module available globally?  I saw some articles on Webpack. Please, no Webpack or any add-on libraries to make this work.

Comment: Are you trying to export both functions with one import statement or are you talking about scope?

Comment: Talking more about scope.  Once the import of the module is completed, I'd want any functions in main.js (global) to be able to access them without doing an import again themselves.

Comment: My first thought is that you can only achieve this by attaching to the window.  Seems after a little searching myself this seems to be the case.  Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52484429/6254263

Comment: ahh..interesting.  I'll read that article a bit more to see how it is done.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The import returns a promise, so you could do so using:

```
// main.js
var bob = import ('./module.js');
bob.then((mod) => {
    console.log(mod);
    for(var prop in mod){
        // maybe a little nicer to check hasOwnProperty?
        // but you get the idea for brevity
        window[prop] = mod[prop];
    }
});
```