# Global scoped imports/includes for javascript?

Tags: javascript, import

I have a massive JS library and I'd like to break it up into discreet files, but I also don't want to have to list a dozen different libraries in my HTML. I'm hoping for something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>   
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>page</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   // mypage
</body>
</html>
```

**common.js:**

```
include("functions.js");
include("load.js");
```

**functions.js:**

```
function foo() {
   alert("bar");
}
```

**load.js:**

```
window.onload = function() {
   foo();
}
```

I want to do this because I don't want to have to list a ton of libraries in every one of my HTML templates. I'd like to list the `common.js`. It's not a deal break, I'm just used to doing the same thing in PHP. Something that is a deal breaker is that it needs to be vanilla javascript.

I've been searching and found a few things, but they all seem to be using frameworks or things beyond vanilla JavaScript. The most promising thing I found was `import()`, but that doesn't seem to import functions at the global scope. Meaning, that when I tried that, it would raise a `foo() is undefined` error.

Is this just a limitation for vanilla JS?

Comment: There's no need to use import. Global scope is how JS used to include multiple libraries in one page

Comment: I think one of us is misunderstanding the other. I'm assuming it's me, so maybe if you could be more direct.


Importing (or including, or loading) them is the whole thing I'm trying to do, so that's where the "need" is. I can't just have the functions.js file sitting there without telling the browser to load it. That's my question. How do I load it?


In other words, if I don't do "import("functions.js"), then what do I do to bring the functions in the functions.js file into the global scope?

Comment: AFAIK, the "old" way of including JS functions into the page is by using `script` tags. This parses the JS and puts them in the global scope. [Using ESM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) does not. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file help?

Comment: The whole point was the avoid a bunch of script tags in every HTML document. I saw that post and the "dynamic load" is the only reasonably close thing for vanilla JS. It has some undesirable behaviors with loading order. Specifically, instead of loading the library where you code it, it loads after all other scripts tags since it works by dynamically creating new script tags at the end of the header element. That post was from 2009; I had hoped JS has added a mechanism to do that by now, something like PHP's "include()". It seems crazy to me that it's still not an built in option. Thankyou

Comment: I can probably get the dynamic load thing to work if I rewrite how I'm doing somethings. If anyone knows of a better or more modern way I'd still love to know

Comment: ESM Imports should be the way to go, but you should consider avoiding the global scope.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483411/how-do-i-avoid-adding-javascript-es6-module-exports-to-global-scope-for-use-in-n?

Comment: I appreciate everyone's suggestions, particularly @evolutionxbox. I tried to get the dynamic load to work and it seemed close, but getting the library loading order just right with our architecture was really causing more problems then this whole thing was supposed to solve.

I think I'm going to go a whole different direction and use my PHP templating class to solve the problem. Specifically, I'm going to use <script> tags to load them, but I'm going to put all of them in a separate HTML fragment, and then that HTML fragment will get plugged into the <head> of all my HTML templates.