# How to enumerate list of available classes in javascript es6

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, enumeration

I want to enumerate the different object types in a large Javascript program.
This has been fairly easy by recursive walking the objects (starting at 'window') and looking at their prototypes.  For example, `function Fred() {...}` shows up in iteration as `window.Fred`

However, `class Bill {...}` does not make `Bill` visible in `window`, and in quite a bit of Google searching I have not managed to find out how I can introspect the system to find `Bill`.  (lots about how to look inside `Bill` once I have found him).  Can anyone tell me how to find the active classes such as `Bill`, please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711603/javascript-es6-class-definition-not-accessible-in-window-global

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript ES6 class definition not accessible in window global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711603/javascript-es6-class-definition-not-accessible-in-window-global)

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. It's not clear what you want it for. If you need to have a list of them for documentation purposes, consider using doc generators like JSDoc or ESDoc.