# How do I refer to a class given its name as a string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

In Perl:

```perl
package Foo {
    sub new { bless {} }
    sub some_method { 42 }
}
my $f = "Foo"->new;
say ref $f;         # 'Foo'
$f->some_method;
```

---

In Python:

```py
class Foo:
    def some_method():
        return 42

f = globals()['Foo']()
print(type(f).__name__)     # 'Foo'
f.some_method
```

---

In Ruby:

```rb
class Foo
    def some_method
        return 42
    end
end

f = Module.const_get('Foo').new
puts f.class            # 'Foo'
f.some_method
```

---

In Javascript:

```js
class Foo {
    some_method() { return 42 }
}

let f = new ?????????????;
console.log(f.constructor.name);    // 'Foo'
f.some_method();
```

If Foo were a plain function and not a class, `this["Foo"]` would work, but how do you deal with classes? I tried `eval`, but the `f` instance will not exist outside the scope, so that solution is not generally suitable.

---

Edit to address possible duplicates: Factories, registries and the like only work when I can refer to an existing class in the factory, but if the classes I want to refer to are not known in advance, I cannot use this work-around.

Comment: new Foo() ....?

Comment: do you mean you want to create an instance of the class based on a string `"foo"` or are you just talking about instantiating a class in a standard way?

Comment: @AnmolMittal: Completely missing the point of the question: The OP wants to refer to Foo by name: `new something['Foo']()`

Comment: TBF, it's not that clear...

Comment: Guys, read the damn question. There's ___3___ examples of other languages where he refers to the class by it's name.

Comment: I don't know any of those languages.....For all I know that's how you instantiate a class in Ruby....

Comment: @Liam: Neither do I, but that doesn't make the snippets incomprehensible. Don't assume those languages _need_ you to wrap a class name in quotes. That's just silly.

Comment: but why you want to make it more complex when you can directly access the class by "Foo" ??

Comment: @AnmolMittal because sometimes you can only know the name of the class you want to instantiate inside a given scope. This question does make sense, it just has already been answered in other posts.

Comment: also because Factory pattern.

Comment: @Logar: That dupe target is basically hardcoding a list of classes. I'm pretty sure that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: By the way, what's wrong with new this["Foo"] ? I mean, if you can make it work with a function, I'm pretty sure you can make it work with a class.

Comment: No, you cant lol

Comment: @Logar: Classes just don't work that way.

Comment: https://repl.it/HTbV

Comment: that's not es6, you are using babel compiler, which basically converts class to function

Comment: Ok, I got your point

Comment: Thanks for the research, this question can be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Copied the relevant part from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40069309/46395:

```js
class Foo {
    some_method() { return 42 }
}

let f = new(eval('Foo'));
console.log(f.constructor.name);    // 'Foo'
f.some_method();
```

Please go upvote that original answer.

Comment: If it's a dupe, CV as dupe, don't answer it.

Answer (score -2):

What I suggest is use some variable for mapping :-

```
class Foo{
 a(){}
}

var class_map = {
 "Foo" : Foo
}

var f = new class_map['Foo']()
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321636/es6-classes-what-about-instrospection/30322216#30322216) it specifies that

> globally-declared classes are globals, but not properties of the
>   global object...

Hence, you have to map explicitly