# how to access class like function from window?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am exploring to use class in javascript. I have below snippet but am not able to find the reason behind why the class is not accessible from window object.

```
function abc(){}
class abcd{}
alert(window.abc);
alert(window.abcd);
alert(abcd);
```

I read many article for class and how it's different from function. I found that its just syntactical sugar and special function. But nowhere mentioned why is it not available on the window? and Where can I find a defined class?

Comment: https://medium.com/@parsyval/javascript-prototype-vs-class-a7015d5473b

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321636/es6-classes-what-about-instrospection