# Get a reference to the script object

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, ide, v8

In V8 at least, in the debugger, you see `local`, `script` and `global` categorizing the variables.

[image]

I got a reference to `global`. All you do for that is set `this` on entry to a property to use later if need be.

However, I can't find how to save a reference to the `script` object. I think it exists because that's what the debugger is looping through in the watch window.

Comment: I cannot seem to get the `script` label. Could you share a sample code to get it?

Comment: @lamblichus, are you using V8? I can't remember if that's when I started seeing the script object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before ES6, All declarations outside a function (and function declaration themselves) were properties of global object.  After ES6, There are two  kinds of global records:

> - Object record- Same as ES5.
>
>   - Function declarations
>   - Function generators
>   - Variable assignments `var`
> - Declarative record - New
>
>   - `let`, `const`, `class`, etc

Those in the declarative record are not accessible from  the global "object", though they are globals themselves. They are accessible from the script, but the object/internal data structure holding the declarative records itself is not accessible or enumerable from inside the script. This declarative record is shown in v8 debugger as properties of `script` object.

#### References:

- [Global environment records](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-global-environment-records)
- Related Answers:

  - [ES6- What about introspection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321636/)
  - [Do let statements create properties on the global object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776079/)

Comment: Thank you. Nice answer. How do you think the GAS debugger is gathering all such declarations under the "script" object for the watch window?

Comment: @toddmo The declarative records are accessible from the debugger.  The "how" is implementation specific and probably proprietory logic, which even if we knew, cannot be replicated without reverse engineering and rebuilding a new custom v8 engine.