# JavaScript class names are the properties of what object?

Tags: javascript, class

This is not about CSS classes and the answer to my question is near impossible to find because of the word "class" in connection with JavaScript usually relates to HTML CSS classes. With that no more words. Just console dialog:

```
> function Foo() {}
< undefined
> window.Foo
< function Foo() {}
> class Bar {}
< undefined
> window.Bar
< undefined
> Foo
< f Foo {}
> Bar
< class Bar() {}
> window.Zoo
< undefined
> Baz
x Uncaught ReferenceError: Baz is not defined
```

Before there was a class keyword we defined classes as functions and those names ended up properties of the window object (at least in the browser). Where are the class names now? How can I delete a class as I can `delete window.Foo`? How can I test a class has been defined without getting a Name is not defined error?

Comment: "Before there was a class keyword" before what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript ES6 class definition not accessible in window global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711603/javascript-es6-class-definition-not-accessible-in-window-global)

Comment: Fascinating question!  I think one of these two posts might have an answer for you: [ES6 classes : what about instrospection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321636/es6-classes-what-about-instrospection) and [Do let statements create properties on the global object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776079/do-let-statements-create-properties-on-the-global-object) (the last one is specific to `let` but I think it still applies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, we're just talking about variables. You're conflating the behavior of global variables with classes. The new-ish `class` keyword is just syntactic sugar around a variable declaration with `let`, the same way `function` was (for our purposes) equivalent to `var`. Classes have *no relevance* to your question. The same way that global variables declared with `let` no longer appear as properties of the global object, so to do variables declared with `class`.

> Before there was a class keyword we defined classes as functions and those names ended up properties of the window object

No, only variables (*all* variables, not just "classes") defined at global scope with `var` or `function` wound up as properties on the global object. A "class" (ie constructor function) or any other variable declared in any other scope would be bound to that scope and would not appear on the global object:

```
function Foo() { }
window.Foo // function Foo() { }
(function () { function Bar() { } })();
window.Bar // undefined
```

> Where are the class names now?

Where they have always been, whether declared with `function` or `var` or `let` or `class`: The scope in which they were declared. Constructors created with `class` are just variables in whatever scope you're in, just like variables.

```
{
  class Foo {}
} // Foo is gone
```

> How can I delete a class as I can `delete window.Foo`

You wouldn't do this. You'd just let it go out of scope, or set the variable to `undefined` if you really want to reuse the variable for some reason:

```
class Foo { }
Foo = undefined;
```

> How can I test a class has been defined without getting a Name is not defined error?

Like you always should have, for all variables, regardless of how they were declared: `typeof`. You never should have been checking for properties in `window` as this only worked for *global* variables.

```
typeof Foo // "undefined"
class Foo { }
typeof Foo // "function"
```